# Grant service principal access to application in other tenant

Tags: azure-active-directory

I have an Azure AD service principal in one tenant (`OneTenant`) that I would like to give access to an application in another tenant (`OtherTenant`).

The service principal in tenant `OneTenant` is a managed service identity for an Azure Logic App. So what I actually want is to call an API from my Logic App. This API is protected by an Azure AD application in `OtherTenant`.

The application in `OtherTenant` defines a number of roles and the service principal in `OneTenant` should have one of these roles so it can call the API.

I tried the following:

- set the app in `OtherTenant` to multi-tenant
- ran the following PS command to attempt to add the SP to a role in the app:

  ```
  New-AzureADServiceAppRoleAssignment `
    -ObjectId <object-id-of-sp-in-one-tenant> `
    -Id <role-id> `
    -PrincipalId <object-id-of-sp-in-one-tenant> `
    -ResourceId <app-id-in-other-tenant>
  ```

  (both logged in in `OneTenant` and `OtherTenant`)

  This gives an error stating that either `app-id-in-other-tenant` or `object-id-of-sp-in-one-tenant` can not be found, depending on where I am signed in.

I also tried creating a Service Principal in `OneTenant` based on the app-id from `OtherTenant` In that case I get an error message: `Authenticating principal does not have permission to instantiate multi-tenantapplications and there is not matching Applicationin the request tenant.`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, I finally got around to testing if the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52659195/23562) presented by Rohit Saigal works. It does point in the right direction but is not complete.

First step is to **create a service principal in `OneTenant` that represents the application in `OtherTenant`**. So while signed in to `OneTenant`, run the following script:

```
$spInOneTenant = New-AzureADServicePrincipal -AppId <app-id-in-other-tenant>
```

Next step is to run the `New-AzureADServiceAppRoleAssignment` cmdlet with the following parameters:

```
New-AzureADServiceAppRoleAssignment `
    -Id <role-id> `
    -ObjectId <object-id-of-sp-in-one-tenant> `
    -PrincipalId <object-id-of-sp-in-one-tenant> `
    -ResourceId $spInOneTenant.ObjectId
```

The trick is to use the object id of the service principal you created in the previous step as the `ResourceId`.

Comment: I like that this is at least an option. I have a backlog item to do something like this in another tenant (big thank you!). How are you authenticating? Can you share secrets?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but this workaround only works if the JWT validation on the resource server fails to validate the authority claim - which is a security hole. The fundamental problem here is that SP from `OneTenant` can not get a token from the `OtherTenant` because there's no way to make `OtherTenant`  aware of the SP from `OneTenant`.

Comment: @EugeneTolmachev no, there are no "get token" operations involved here. ServicePrincipal created in current tenant is *representation* of that App-id-in-other-tenant in the current tenant for purpose of granting permissions (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54066287/azure-service-principal-id-vs-application-id). Basically code says "whenever app-id-in-other-tenant tries to create token call app-id-in-one-tenant check if spInOneTenant was granted any roles for it".

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov the "get token" is implied. This is why this whole granting is being discussed - to get access to an application, i.e. acquire token from AAD given the app as the target scope/resource. You can instantiate *my* multi-tenant application in *your* tenant, but each AAD tenant will issue it's own "authority" claim - this is by design and correctly implemented claims verification MUST check that the token-issuing authority is the one it trusts. I.e you can't call *my* service, if you obtain the token using *your* AAD tenant, unless I specify your AAD as the issuing authority.

Answer (score 4):

Taking the command as is from your question:

```
New-AzureADServiceAppRoleAssignment `
  -ObjectId <object-id-of-sp-in-one-tenant> `
  -Id <role-id> `
  -PrincipalId <object-id-of-sp-in-one-tenant> `
  -ResourceId <app-id-in-other-tenant>
```

Try changing the last parameter value i.e. ResourceId

Currently you're passing `<app-id-in-other-tenant>`

Replace that with `<object-id-of-API-in-other-tenant>`

Comment: @RonaldWildenberg did the suggestion work for you or still facing issues?

Comment: Sorry, busy with other stuff. Testing right now if this works.

Comment: Still waiting for someone to run part of my PS script because I do not have sufficient privileges to execute all of it

Comment: Hi Rohit, I tried the same, but it does not work: New-AzureADServiceAppRoleAssignment : Error occurred while executing NewServicePrincipalAppRoleAssignment
Code: Request_ResourceNotFound
Message: Resource '<object-id-of-API-in-other-tenant>' does not exist or one of its queried reference-property objects are not present.

Comment: @Tom is your scenario exactly like the one described in question above or there are some differences?

Comment: It is exactly the same. We have an API in one tenant(A) and want to give a logic app in another tenant(B) access to this API. We now solved it by creating an identity for the logic app in tenant B and using oAuth instead of 'managed identity' authentication in the logic app.

Answer (score 0):

The question/answers presented here were helpful, but yet it took me some time to work through the details and actually make it work, so allow me to elaborate some more on the above, as it might help others too.

### Scenario

Two tenants:

- `Home Tenant`.
- `Other Tenant`.

One Azure App Service `API app`, with access managed by the `Home Tenant`.

One `Logic app` placed in a subscription in `Other Tenant` that need to securely access the `API app` in the `Home Tenant`.

### Approach

#### Application registration

For the `API app` to delegate identity and access management to Azure AD an `application` is registered in the `home tenant`’s Azure Active Directory. The `application` is registered as a multi-tenant app.

You also need to create an app role (see documentation: [How to: Add app roles in your application and receive them in the token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-add-app-roles-in-azure-ad-apps)), lets call it `read.weather`.

#### Configuration of `Other Tenant` and `Logic App`

To provide the `Logic App` access to the `API app` do this:

1. Enable a *system assigned* identity for the `logic app` - i.e. use [Managed Identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/create-managed-service-identity). Note down the system assigned managed identity `Object ID` (`{18a…}`), you will need it in a minute.
2. Create a service principal for the `application` in the `Other Tenant` using this command, where `appId` is the appId of the `application` registered in `Home Tenant` (e.g. lets say it’s `{1a3}` here):

`New-AzureADServicePrincipal -AppId {appId}`

This command will output a json document which includes among other things an `objectId` for the service principal just created.

```json
[... more json ...]
"objectId": "b08{…}",
[... more json...]
```

You should also see the appRoles, including the app role `read.weather` you just created, om the json output from the  `New-AzureADServicePrincipal` command:

```json
[... more json...]
  "appRoles": [
    {
      "allowedMemberTypes": [
        "Application"
      ],
      "description": "Read the weather.",
      "displayName": "Read Weather",
      "id": "46f{…}",
      "isEnabled": true,
      "value": "read.weather"
    }
  ],
[... more json...]
```

3. To tie it all together make an app role assignment using the command:

`New-AzureADServiceAppRoleAssignment -Id {app role ide} -ObjectId {system assigned identity object id} -PrincipalId {system assigned identity object id} -ResourceId {object id of service principal}`

E.g. something like this:

`New-AzureADServiceAppRoleAssignment -Id 46f… -ObjectId 18a… -PrincipalId 18a… -ResourceId b08…`

4. Now we are ready to set up the HTTP request in the `Logic App` using the URI to the `API app` using Managed Identity for authentication.

Notice that the audience is needed and has the form: `api://{appId}`.

[image: Logic App configuration]

### But wait…!

Does this mean that anyone could do this, if only they know the appId of your `application` registration, and wouldn’t this compromise the security of the `API app`?

Yes, it does, and yes indeed it could compromise the security of the `API app`.

If you look at the access token being created and used as bearer from the `Logic App` it is a valid access token, which contains all the necessary claims, including the app role(s). The access token is however issued by `Other Tenant` and not `Home Tenant`.

Therefore, if you have a multi tenanted application and you want to guard it against this scenario, then you could check the issuer (`tid` more likely) of the incoming access token calling the API and only accept it if the issuer is the `Home Tenant`, or you could make the `application` a single tenant app.

Or, you could require that the issuer matches a list of tenants that the API trusts.