# Where can I find Azure Function Permissions?

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I am trying to create a role for fine grained access to an Azure Function App. Trying to find Function permissions:

[image]

I would of expected to see the `Microsoft Functions` card - I've done a quick scroll and there's nothing that implies or is related to `Function`. Where can I find Azure Function App permissions?

Comment: Is it at app registration level ? What are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: Yes at the app registration level. Trying to use Managed Identities to add authentication between my function app and a vm. Idk if this is misuse of Managed Identities but this article seemed to imply it's possible: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/spring-apps/tutorial-managed-identities-functions

Comment: so the vm needs to authenticate to the function app or the other way around ?

Comment: VM needs to authenticate to the function app.

So I was thinking of attaching a role assignment to the vm's managed identity, which is why I was looking for Function permissions

Comment: if you have an app registration for to authenticate to the function app, you would need to do app role assignment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67169780/how-to-explicitly-grant-access-from-a-user-managed-identity-to-a-aad-application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to create a custom role and set permissions for Azure Function Apps use "Microsoft Web Apps" card as Azure Functions are a part of Azure Web Apps:

[image]